# MS Access - Use result from query to calculate field value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to pull some data from a query in my database into a calculated field in a table. I have dates entered for some jobs I'm recording (`DateCallOpened`, `DateQuoteSent`, `DateQuoteReceived`), as well as `WorkType` for each job to track the type of work done. I've used calculated fields to find the time it took for each record between those dates. I've also used `qryTimings` to find the average length of time for the `WorkType`.

I'd like to build fields that showed the `ProjectedQuoteSent`, and use the data from my query to calculate the date I can expect the quote to be sent, but I just can't figure out how to pull that data out of the query. I was hoping it would be something as simple as:

```
=[DateCallOpened]+[qryTimings]:[Avg Of TimeToSendQuote]
```

Comment: Mind the colon you put in your reference "[qryTimings]:[Avg Of TimeToSendQuote]", that should be an exclamation point. Though, you cannot reference a query field in this way, see my answer for a solution. It may have been a typo, but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DLookup() function to grab your value from your query. So your formula would be something like:

```
=[DateCallOpened]+DLookup("Avg Of TimeToSendQuote", "qryTimings", _
  "[WorkType]=" & [Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtWorkTypeInput])
```

See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)  for more info.

Comment: I tried that, but Access came back with an error that the string was too long.

Comment: @DonovanFox Does `[Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtWorkTypeInput]` output anything? What's the length of the output? Then test `Dlookup("Avg of TimeToSendQuote", "qryTiming", "[WorkType]= " & [Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtWorkTypeInput])`. Does that throw the same error?